# Redirect non-existent subpages to second part of url

Tags: redirect

We have many different departments, who have their own custom abbreviation. For example: `ga`, `de`, `ka-da`. Every department has its own custom logo and intro text. I would like to achieve, that there is only one single front-page and f.e. one single contact page, but the logo and text which should appear is depending on the abbreviation. (Not like multi-language plugins // Only one single page which has multiple fields for each department made with ACF PRO)

https://url.de/ --> show front-page
https://url.de/ga/ --> show front-page, but let me get the /ga/ as an var, so i can adapt the logo and text
https://url.de/contact/ --> show contact-page
https://url.de/ga/contact/ --> show the contact-page, but let me get the /ga/ as an var, so i can adapt the logo and text

I tried using the following code to test the redirect in generell, but i am not sure if this is the right way to achieve what i need.

```
global $post;
add_rewrite_rule( '^ga\/(.*)\/?', "index.php?page_id={$post->ID}", 'top' );
```

I always get an 404.
Any ideas how to get this work? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the complete function? what is the hook you are using?

Comment: this is all. I tried it with `add_rewrite_rule( '^ga\/(.*)\/?', "index.php?page_id={1}", 'top' );` and flushed the permalinks, but still only the 404 page is presented when trying to open page https://url.de/ga/

Comment: Are you referring to just Pages (i.e. post type of `page`)?

Comment: @SallyCJ should also work for posts, not only pages

Comment: How about category, tag, etc. archive pages? Should also work on those pages? If so, then a simple redirect, for example: redirect `http://example.com/ga/contact` to `http://example.com/contact/?department=ga`, might be a *better* option for you..

Comment: Unfortunately it *must* be the structure i described.